# Image not clickable

Tags: image, hyperlink

I have a cover of a book that I want to be clickable but I can't get the link to be the image.

```
    <div class="imagePage">
          <a href="../index.php">
            <img src="../images/covers/denmark.jpg" alt="Denmark">
          </a>
    </div>

    .imagePage {
           float: left;
           border-top: 30px;
           padding-right: 30px;
     }
```

Please can anyone help. I wonder if my media queries are interfering:

```
    /* xs */
img {
    width: 150px;
    height: auto;
}
/* sm */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    img {
        width: 200px;
    }
}
/* md */
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    img {
        width: 350px;
    }
}
/* lg */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    img {
        width: 500px;
    }
}
```

Edit: I am using bootstrap. Here is my whole **CSS:**

```
body {
        padding-top: 30px;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Candara, Calibri, Segoe, "Segoe UI", Optima, Arial,          sans-serif !important;

  }

    @media (max-width: 979px) {
      body {
        padding-top: 30px;
      }
    }

    /* xs */
    img {
        width: 150px;
        height: auto;
    }
    /* sm */
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        img {
            width: 200px;
        }
    }
    /* md */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        img {
            width: 350px;
        }
    }
    /* lg */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        img {
            width: 500px;
        }
    }

    /* xs */
    p {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    /* sm */

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        p {
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    }

    /* md */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        p {
            font-size: 16px;
    }
    }

    /* lg */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        p {
            font-size: 18px;
        }
    }

    /* xs */
    h1 {
        font-size: 28px !important;
    }

    /* sm */

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        h1 {
            font-size: 50px !important;
        }
    }

    /* md */
    @media (min-width: 992px) {
        h1 {
            font-size: 84px !important;
    }
    }

    /* lg */
    @media (min-width: 1200px) {
        h1 {
            font-size: 96px !important;
        }
    }


    .navbar-left img {
      width: auto;
    }

    .sm-bt img {
      width: auto;
    }

    .end img {
      width: auto;
    }

    .titlePage img {
      max-width: 280px;
    }


    /*---Start Parallax---*/

    .parallax-top {
      background-image: url("../images/hero3.jpg"); 
      height: 1200px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;

    }

    .main .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0;
    }

    .main .caption h1 {
      margin-top: 0px;
    }

    .main .caption p {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }


    .parallax-middle {
      background-image: url("../images/hero1.jpg"); 
      height: 1200px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .caption-middle {  
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 1%;
    }

    .parallax-bottom {
      background-image: url("../images/hero2.jpg"); 
      height: 1200px;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

    .caption-bottom {  
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
         background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        padding: 1%;
        height: auto;
    }

    /*---End Parallax---*/

    .box {
      height: 200px;
      font-size: 40px;
      margin-top: 80px;
      text-align: center;

    }

    .thumbs {
      margin-right: 15px;
      max-width: auto;
    }

    .thumbnail {
      border: none !important;
    }

    .fb-page {
      margin-right: 50px;
    }


    .footer {
        padding-top: 5px;
      position: relative;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background-color: #fff;
      text-align: center;

    }

    .footer p {
      font-size: 12px;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .footer p {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
       .footer p {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    }


    .sm-bt a {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 12px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }

    hr { 
        display: block;
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        margin-bottom: 0.5em;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-style: inset;
        border-width: 1px;
    }

    .pageOuter {
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    .imagePage {
      float: left;
      border-top: 30px;
      padding-right: 30px;
    }

    .blurb {
      display: block;
      position: relative;

     }

    /*---Title Pages---*/

    .pageOuter {
    background-image: url("../images/background.png");

    }

    .titlePage {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px
     }

    .titlePage .jumbotron {
    width: 45%;
    font-size: 14px;
    float: right;
    padding: 25px !important;
    margin-right: 0px;
    opacity: 0.7;

    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 468px) {

    .titlePage .jumbotron p {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .titlePage .jumbotron h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    .titlePage .jumbotron p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .titlePage .jumbotron h3 {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    }

    .titlePage .container {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin-right: 0px;
    }

    .titlePage h1 {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .titlePage h2 {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .titlePage h3 {
    text-align: center; 
    }

    .titlePage p {
    color: #4d4d4d;
    line-height: 1.59;
    margin-top: 0em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    }

    .titleDetails ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    }

    .titleDetails ul li {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    line-height: 1.59;

    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {

      .titleDetails ul li {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    line-height: 1.59;
    }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {

    .titleDetails ul li {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    line-height: 1.59;
    }
    }

    .titleDetails h3 {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    }

    .titleDetails {
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;

    }

    /*---End Title Pages---*/


    /*---Start Contact---*/

     .contactPage {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      padding-top: 30px;
      padding-bottom: 30px;

    }

    .contactPage h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .contactPage .jumbotron {
      width: 40%;
      padding: 10px;
      position: center;
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 468px) {

    .contactPage .jumbotron p {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .contactPage .jumbotron h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    .contactPage .jumbotron p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .contactPage .jumbotron h3 {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    }

    .home-btn {
      text-align: center;
    }

    /*---end Contact---*/

    .regionPage {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    /*---Start Africa---*/
    .africaHero {
      background-image: url("../images/africaHero.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .africaHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;
    }

    /*---end Africa---*/

    /*---Start Author---*/
    .authorHero {
      background-image: url("../images/hero4.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .authorHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;
    }


    /*---end Author---*/

    /*---Start Asia--*/
    .asiaHero {
      background-image: url("../images/asiaHero.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .asiaHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;
    }

    /*---end asia---*/

    /*---Start Australasia---*/


    /*---End Australasia---*/

    .australasiaHero {
      background-image: url("../images/australasiaHero.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .australasiaHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;

    }

    /*---Start N America---*/
    .namericaHero {
      background-image: url("../images/namericaHero.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .namericaHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;
    }

    /*---end N America---*/


    /*---Start S America---*/

    .samericaHero {
      background-image: url("../images/samericaHero.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .samericaHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;

      }

    /*---End S America--*/

    /*---Start Europe---*/

    .europeHero {
      background-image: url("../images/europeHero.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .europeHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;

      }


    /*---Start Why CS---*/

    .whyHero {
    background-image: url("../images/hero5.jpg");
      height: 1200px;
      background-position: top;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
    }

    .whyHero .caption {  
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        opacity: 0.75;
        height: auto;
        padding: 0.5%;
    }

    /*---end Why CS---*/

    /*---Start authors---*/

    .authors .caption {
      text-align: center;

    }

    .authorPage img {
      display: block;
      margin: auto;

    }

    .authorPage p {
      margin-top: 25px;
    }


    .authorPage {
      width: 80%;
      margin: auto;

     }

    .authorPage h1 {
    text-align: center;
    }

    .authorPage .container{
        display: flex
    }

    .authorPage .jumbotron {
      width: 40%;
      padding: 3px;
      position: center;
      margin: 5%;
    }

    .authorPage ul {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding-left: 0;
    }


    @media screen and (min-width: 468px) {

    .authorPage .jumbotron p {
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    .author .jumbotron h3 {
      font-size: 18px;
    }
    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    .authorPage .jumbotron p {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    .authorPage .jumbotron h3 {
      font-size: 24px;
    }
    }
    /*---End authors---*/

    /*---start team---*/

    h1 {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .team1 {

      padding: 2%;
    }

    .team2 {

      padding: 2%;
    }

    .team1 img {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 10px;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .team2 img {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 15px;
      padding: 10px;
    }
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/mwille14/pen/MpbwNo)

Comment: the tag seems to be correct. it will show the image click able. what is the issue here

Comment: When I inspect it the link seems to run across the center of the image, behind it and not filling the whole image.

Comment: Is your image is loaded? if yes it should cover the whole image. Do you have any other common style applied

Comment: Yes image is loaded on the page. Using bootstrap. I wonder if I need to do anything different? Have added all CSS

Comment: There is no issue with the styling. May i know which browser you are checking

Comment: I am using Google Chrome

Comment: I am not having any issue with your code. hyperlink sign is showing when i mouse over the image.

Comment: What do you suggest? I could share the page locally with you?

Comment: Can you create a code pen and share

Comment: https://codepen.io/mwille14/pen/evBNxR

Comment: Any luck with the image?

Comment: Seems like you missed to close the `<div class="titlePage">`. Can you try with add `</div>` before `<div class="blurb">`

Comment: It's closed on line 52...

Comment: please check the answer and let me know if you still have issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i have fixed the issue by adding position and z-index to your **imagePage** div. Please check the styling below and please let me know.

```
.imagePage {
  float: left;
  border-top: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```